# how to iterate to a specific element location in an array

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I have a line of DNA(genetics) text. A like is 3 BILLION elements wide if inserted into an array. I have another file with the specific location numbers of the items i want. I would like to go straight to that elementLocation and get the value in there. What is the most efficient way to do this?

In other words, tellling java to "go to location 2234834 and get me the item in there.", but in an iterative manner...I have about 1 Milllion locations to go through

Comment: I am thinking of making a whole new LinkedMap for each line and adding the elements into that Map, with a count of elements as Map keys and elements as MapValues?

Comment: What's the format of the DNA file? Any chance you can post a few lines - i'm struggling to understand this question.

Comment: It is a text file, on MapReduce. It is DNA nucleotides: "A C G T G C T A A C C T A G C A T C "

Comment: Ok, I don't know what MapReduce is or nucleotides - I have to admit as far as anything to do with genetics is involved i'm a little out of my depth. However, you will maybe want to take a look at Javas RandomAccessFile, there is a tutorial here:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html

And the javadoc here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: That makes much more sense to me. Check out the links above - you'll find exactly what you need there.

Comment: How about the file which contains a list of the locations, are they on a new line? I am imagining something like: 24, 55, 120, 222,... where each number represents the part you want from the DNA file? What format is the second file in? Perhaps I can make an example - although it will just be based on the information on the RandomAccessFile tutorial as that's exactly what you want (by the sounds of it). Example would have to be tomorrow though - I have to dash off. I'll check how you are getting on in the morning (unless someone else makes it before me).